# Dúvida exercício pedra papel e tesoura

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante na programação e descobri um site massinha pra começar o tal de codeacademy, porém eles tem alguns erros e tals dificultando a minha compreensão.

Estou no seguinte exercício de javascript:

> Escolha do Computador: Parte 2   Temos computerChoice, mas ele agora é
>   igual a um número aleatório entre 0 e 1. Precisamos de algum modo
>   traduzir esse número aleatório em uma escolha entre pedra, papel e
>   tesoura. Como faremos isso?!
>
> Se computerChoice estiver entre 0 e 0.33, faça computerChoice igual a
>   "pedra". Se computerChoice estiver entre 0.34 e 0.66, faça
>   computerChoice igual a "papel".   Se computerChoice estiver entre 0.67
>   e 1, faça computerChoice igual a "tesoura". Mas há três resultados! If
>   / else nos permite apenas dois resultados. E agora?! Precisamos usar
>   if / else if / else. Leia a dica para a sintaxe completa. Você vai
>   achar graça de tão fácil ela é.
>
> Instruções Sob seu código já existente, escreva a declaração if / else
>   if / else Nos respectivos blocos de código, mude o valor de
>   computerChoice com base nas regras acima. Lembre-se, você NÃO precisar
>   usar var quando estiver mudando o valor de uma variável já existente.

Detalhe: Eles não me ensinaram a fazer `if else` junto.

Tenho que fazer um joguinho de pedra, papel e tesoura seguindo essas instruções.

Segue como escrevi o código:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Você escolhe pedra, papel ou tesoura?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log (computerChoice);

if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  console.log("Pedra");
} else if (computerChoice Não sei o que colocar aqui (tem alguma função "entre") {
  console.log("Papel");
} else (computerChoice > 0.67) {
  console.log("Tesoura");
}
```

Se poderem me ajudar para eu avançar no curso!

Comment: A condição "entre", no seu caso é: maior que 0.34 e menor que 0.66.

Comment: Essa pergunta tem dois votos de fechamento como ampla demais. Embora essa com certeza não seja uma de nossas melhores perguntas, discordo dos votos de fechamento. Esta pergunta não tem nada de amplo nela (pelo contrário, é bem restrita, uma vez que trata-se de uma dúvida acerca de uma única linha de código). Além disso, acredito que os outros motivos de fechamento não se aplicam (não é duplicata, é sobre programação, não é opinativo, a pergunta é clara, não é erro de digitação, é reproduzível e está em português).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que estude um pouco mais, acho que você precisa "voltar" um pouco e aprender mais sobre os fundamentos de programação (lógica) e da linguagem, que é mais ou menos onde você vai aprender sobre [operadores de comparação e lógicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators). Nesse link tem uma tabela completa com todos os operadores e descrição do que são.

No seu caso vai precisar dos operadores *maior-que* `>` e *menor-que* `<`:

```
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  console.log("Pedra");
} else if (computerChoice>0.33 && computerChoice<0.67) {
  console.log("Papel");
} else (computerChoice >= 0.67) {
  console.log("Tesoura");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acetil, você pode usar `computerChoice > 0.33 && computerChoice <= 0.67`

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Você escolhe pedra, papel ou tesoura?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log (computerChoice);

if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  console.log("Pedra");
} else if (computerChoice > 0.33 && computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  console.log("Papel");
} else {
  console.log("Tesoura");
}
```

porém acredito que uma melhor solução, seria gerar um numero aleatorio entre 1 e 3 e fazer um `switch`.

```js
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min  
}

var num = getRandom(1, 3);
switch (num) {
  case 1: console.log("Pedra"); break;
  case 2: console.log("Papel"); break;
  case 3: console.log("Tesoura"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas faça assim na condicional do "papel"

```
else if (computerChoice > 0.33 && computerChoice < 0.67) {

 console.log("Papel");
```

Normalmente não há um recurso como

```
if (valor entre x e y) {

}
```

Tem que comparar explicitamente

```
if (variavel > x && variavel < y) {

}
```

Aprenda sobre os operadores lógicos da linguagem:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators